# How can I use TesseractOCRiOS with Spanish?

Tags: ios, xcode, ocr, tesseract, sigabrt

Of course I added the relevant Spanish files and I initialized it like this: `G8Tesseract(language: "spa")`; but it just keeps giving me the same error (which isn't even very clear). In English it works just fine, by the way; it's probably an issue with the data files, but I couldn't find more of them. Any ideas or something?:(

[image: Tesseract error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong data file. Tesseract for iOS doesn't support Tesseract's last version. You must look for the TESSERDATA files for version 3.02. If you use newer files you get that error.

Take the files for Tesseract ver. 3.02 from here: [tesserdata files](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files). At the bottom of the page you'll find the files to download.

Test it in Tesseract-only mode. CUBE doesn't always work with non English languages.

Comment: But I'm using TesseractOCRiOS 4.0.0... Still?

Comment: Try to take the files for Tesseract 3.02 from this link https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files. Let me know if that fixes your problem. I'm using tesseract in English+Italian and it works. Tesseract version is different form the version of the iOS implementation

Comment: I updated the post. You'll get more info there. If you need help let me know.

Comment: Setting it to `.tesseractOnly` did the trick, though the accuracy is clearly taking a bad hit :/ Do you know why it doesn’t work in cube mode? I even included a bunch of cube files… Thank you, by the way.

Comment: The problem are the cube data files. It looks like only the English versions are good. I had problems with other languages